# Flutter - How get country from coordinates without internet?

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation

I have flutter app with geolocation. I use this [plugin](https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-geolocator). 
According to the coordinates I need to determine the country. I can use the plugin for this. It works while there is internet. But I also need to identify the country when the Internet is not available. I found only one solution:

import the database with the coordinators of the main cities and determine the country according to them.

maybe there is a simpler solution?

Answer (score 1):

use [geohash](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_geohash)

```
void main() {
 GeoHasher geoHasher = GeoHasher();
  // country level precision: 10
  myGeoCountryLevelCoord := geoHasher.encode(-98, 38, precision: 10);

  // now you need to download countries geohashes and match it, won't be many, small file only

 }
```

check [countries global geohash map](http://geohash.gofreerange.com/)

Comment: How  I can use this library for get country from coordinates?

Comment: you can't, you need to find elsewhere and then do pattern matching